# Slide lock or flip lock for FPC connector?

Tags: connector, fpc

I'm looking at different connectors for for an FPC cable, and I've narrowed it down to two nearly identical connectors, whose only difference in the lock. One uses a "slide lock":
[image: slide lock]

While the other uses a "flip lock":
[image: flip lock]

I get the conceptual difference between the two, but is there any advantage in using one over the other? For example, does one offer greater mechanical strength for the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have broken more of the flip-lock style than the slide-lock, but that might just be me...

If the flip-lock tab breaks then there's nothing else to do with that connector.  But if the slide-lock breaks, you can sometimes push the locking mechanism into place with a toothpick or small screwdriver.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this thread while searching for different FFC locking mechanisms and thought I'll leave this piece of info for future reference.

From personal experience with flip locks: you have to be careful if cable bends upward from locking mechanism - during vibrations (shipping/use) it might unlock itself, especially if used with short but stiff cabling.