# How to fix a broken flap FCC connector flip-lock ZIF

Tags: ffc, zif

While repairing a projector, I broke the flap holding the flat flex cable (FFC) in place. It's the type "flip-lock" and is ZIF (Zero Insertion Force) so without the flap in position, the connector doesn't work.

I've tried to contact some FFC connector manufacturers, but they were not able to help identify the part. Please mind that the only thing I know is that has 84 pins.

I read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231827/) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/137060/) that my challenge isn't easy, but I'm willing to give a try.

Do you have an idea of which manufacturer might produce such connectors?

Do you have an idea about how to fix it, rather than inserting a spacer under the FFC?

Thanks a lot.
I hope to have been enough clear and precise.

[image: FFC out of the connector]

[image: Connector with broken flap (white part)]

Comment: Last time I used the lid of some plastic container which was just the correct thickness + hot melt glue. Still working to this day.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help/opinions.

At the end I was able to fix it with two layers of magic tape under the FPC as a spacer. It's pretty tight so I suppose it won't come lose any time soon.

I hope that others will benefit from this tip :)

PS: The connector is from an EPSON beamer from the EMP-TWx000 family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector most likely has markings on opposing sides of the connector for "84" and "DDK" on the cable insertion side.

The connector in question is this one from Japanese manufacturer DDK: http://www.ddknet.co.jp/English/products/print/fpc-connectors/ff22e/index.html

The connector is used by my knowledge at least on TW3200 (Epson 8350 in the US) and Panasonic PT-AE1000,PT-AE2000,PT-AE3000,PT-AE4000 projectors.

Similar models probably include at least TW2800, TW2900, Epson 6100 / TW3800, TW4500, TW5500, EH-TW5900, TW6000, TW6000, Epson 6030 / TW9000, EH-TW8000, EH-TW9000, EH-TW90000W, EH-TW9100

Other Panasonic 1080p models across their professional and home cinema projectors are also very likely to contain the same kind of connectors.

Most likely many Epson models which share the same housing designs also share the same 84pin DDK connector. This should be true at least for 1080p projectors, since they will probably have the same amount of connectors on the LCD panel cables across a manufacturer regardless of the model.

The connector FF22E-084B-R13A-S-3H is apparently slightly different in moulding to at least the ones on Panasonic models. Most likely it is still fully compatible replacement.
**I recently found the full connector part number from A Panasonic projector service manual. The part number is FF22C-084B-R13A-C3**

**I am still confident the connector is functionally the same to the S-3H connector. Of course I cannot be completely sure without ever seeing the S-3H in person). I'd like to know if it is possible to transfer the cam part of the S-3H connector to the -C3 connector. Again, the only difference seems to be in the moulding of the plastic parts, while the pinout and overall dimensions remain the same**

**Also Panasonic part number K1MY84BA0200 is listed, and according to this discussion, the connector was available for a feasible price ~15$ at least at some point. https://www.avforums.com/threads/ae4000-problems-please-help.1752032/page-2**

Now when it comes to replacing or fixing the connector, it is no easy task and also not very cheap, since the quotes I got for a single connector started from 30$/pc

Replacing the cam is possible all the way until the pins are bent too much or completely broken, after which it is impossible to refit the cam to the connector. I have successfully refitted the cam part from a Panasonic AE2000 to AE4000, which had all the parts that support the cam gone. Thus the cam can be carefully installed, even when the connector is partly broken. Of course there is still the problem of sourcing the cams themselves. I am not sure if the cams are moulded exactly the same as the ones on my Panasonics.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked a lot with FPC connectors, and that pin layout looks very much like is used by some of the Hirose and Panasonic FPC connectors, however, their websites don't show as having an 84 contact connector in production.

In my experience, I have found that when it comes to mass produced electronic goods, some of the connectors are custom made, and therefore near to impossible to find as a replacement.

I assume that the likely hood of working on this connector in the future is fairly low, and therefore I suggest that you insert the FPC with a spacer, and then hold it in place with some hot glue, or any kind of adhesive, that can be easily removed, in case you needed to do some maintenance on the projector.

Answer (score 0):

I found it on Alibaba: [New Connector FF22E-084B-R13A-S-3H In Stock](https://m.alibaba.com/product/1600294223048/New-Connector-FF22E-084B-R13A-S.html?__sceneInfo=%7B%22type%22:%22appDetailShare%22,%22data%22:%7B%22filterKey%22:%227.8.2_share%22,%22cacheTime%22:%221800000%22%7D%7D&from=share&ckvia=share_D9142C19A400406B8E4EF1D59EDE6D8C)

Minimum quantity is 1, but you have to convince them to send them to you…

Comment: Ok, it is costly: 20$/piece and 15$ shipment (to Germany)